# react-lazy-load-image-component Getting Error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, react-lazy-load

I'm using the React Testing Library, and when the component I'm rendering contains a LazyLoadImage from "react-lazy-load-image-component" I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')".

Here's a picture of the error I got:

[image]

And this is the image of the code snippet in the component that I rendered:

[image]

If anyone is experiencing the same thing as me and has found a solution I really appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was having the similar kind of error ( Not exactly the same ) and resolved by changing few things.

1. You are planning of assigning the value to **src** of LazyloadImage component only if :
   a. It contains image which is inside of meta ( which is intern inside of article ) and you are not sure that all the time these parameters be present.
2. You have added a logical and condition to check the presence of each element in hierarchy so that there won't be an issue of **cannot find an element of undefined**
3. The main thing is what if any of that condition block falls on false condition ?

At that time, your image tag receive **src as false** ( src accepts the string not boolean )

so,

Instead of `<LazyLoadImage src={article && article.meta && article.meta.image} >`

use : `{article && article.meta && article.meta.image && <LazyLoadImage src={article.meta.image} >}`

This will check the existence of src before compiling to the browser.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for sharing, unfortunately it still doesn't solve my problem 